# Change text of "and others" in \citeauthor

Tags: biblatex, acronyms, locale

The default localisation of `biblatex` abbreviates additional authors in `\citeauthor` to ”*et al.*“. I think it's related to the text written by `\ifmorenames`.

How to change the localisation but keep this abbreviation?

Comment: But that's an international localisation! What is the exact problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a default `biblatex` localisation. But the (American) `english` localisation, which was used as a fallback in older versions, indeed uses 'at al.' for `andothers`.

If you are using a different localisation where the text for `andothers` is translated to a string you don't like, you can easily change it back to 'et al.' as follows.

```
\documentclass[dutch]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{dutch}{
  andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson,aksin}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (Sigfridsson en Ryde 1998; Aksın et al. 2006)]